# do not to pass a value with <f:param in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am try to pass a value to other bean, but does not work, apparently the get and set methods are not called.. see my code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">

<p:outputLabel  
    value="Label: "/>
   <p:inputText id="inputtext" value="#{bean1.title}"/>

<p:button
    value="Submit" 
           outcome="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/formBean2">
           <f:param name="value" value="#{bean1.title}"/>
</p:button>
```

### Bean2

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

   String title = Util.getRequestParameter("value");
   method();//this method need of variable title

}
```

### Util

```
public static String getRequestParameter(String name) {
   return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
             .getRequestParameterMap().get(name);
 }
```

Well, i dont know why but it always sends the value null.

someone has an idea of ​​what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I wont dive into the issue since you are using a wrong approach on JSF and I think I can guide you in the right direction.

You should access the `title` value of `Bean1` ***from*** the `Bean2`.

You need to use a `ManagedProperty` like this example (not tested):

```
public class Bean2 {

    @ManagedProperty //maybe youll need (value="#{bean1}")
    private Bean1 bean1;

    // Getter and setter for Bean1

}
```

After you fire your request the JSF framework will apply your `title` value on the `Bean1`. It belongs to that bean, so keep it there.

In your action in `Bean2` you can then make a `getTitle()` from `Bean1` reference. The title is going to be there, and the container is going to inject the dependency from `Bean1` into `Bean2`.

This is the right way to do it.

I recommend you to do a quick example outside your application so you can see that it works, and afterwards you can adapt to your project.

See this example: [Injecting Managed Beans In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/)

**UPDATE**

Notice that if you are using `ViewScoped` beans you need to stay in the same application (aka page) in order to access injected beans. If you need to navigate between views, you gonna need [Faces Flow](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-configure003.htm).

Comment: thanks, i already tested using <f:setPropertyActionListener /> and ManagedProperty, worked but, I need to follow standards that are set for this project I'm working, so i need use a <p:button> and <f:param for this work